# SQL Query add calculated temp column

Tags: sql

I am returning two columns in a query (`date` and `total`).

e.g.

```
date1, 11231

date2, 11239

date3, 11341
```

what I was wondering if I could do would be to create another column in the query that shows me the difference from the last total?

I am not able to change the structure of the sql table at all, is this best suited in a view?

thanks for any help.

Regards

Jason

Comment: Also, which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use LAG() Analytic function if available in your version of SQL-you did not specify. There is also LEAD() function available...

Comment: @user1176737-You are welcome. Try to specify version of your SQL. Also, try creating sample data as in veljasije's answer/example. This will help us to help you better. And last do not forget accept answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying something, maybe will help:

**TABLE CREATION**

```
create table Demo (TotalDate date, Total int);

insert into Demo(TotalDate, Total) 
values ('2012-01-01', 11000);

insert into Demo(TotalDate, Total) 
values ('2012-02-02', 12000);

insert into Demo(TotalDate, Total) 
values ('2012-03-03', 14000);
```

**SELECT QUERY**

```
SELECT
  TotalDate ,
  Total,
  (SELECT TOP 1 d.Total - d1.Total 
     FROM Demo d1 WHERE d1.TotalDate < d.TotalDate ORDER BY d.TotalDate ASC) AS SubTotal
FROM
  Demo d
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012 you could use [LAST_VALUE over partitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231517.aspx).